# Segfault when accessing allocated memory via frame pointer mips

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, stack, mips, mips32

I am writing a simple compiler from c90 to MIPS and I am at the point of code generation. I have this c code as input:

```
int main(){
    int a=50, b=10, c=a+b;
    return c;
}
```

and the code my compiler generates is:

```
    .text   
    .align  2
    .globl main
    .ent main
    .type main, @function
main:
    addiu   $sp, $sp, -24       # Allocate memory on the stack
    sw      $fp, 20($sp)        # Store value of fp on the bottom of the stack
    addiu   $fp, $sp, 16        # Modify fp to point to the the bottom of the available stack memory
    sw      $ra, 0($fp)     # Store the return address for the subroutine
    li      $t0, 50
    sw      $t0, 4($fp)
    li      $t0, 10
    sw      $t0, 8($fp)
    addiu   $sp, $sp, -28       # Allocate more memory
    lw      $t0, 4($fp)
    sw      $t0, 16($fp)
    lw      $t0, 8($fp)
    sw      $t0, 20($fp)
    lw      $t0, 16($fp)
    lw      $t1, 20($fp)
    addu    $t2, $t0, $t1
    sw      $t2, 12($fp)
    lw      $t0, 12($fp)
    sw      $t0, 24($fp)
    lw      $v0, 24($fp)
    lw      $ra, 0($fp)     # Load return address in register 31
    lw      $fp, -4($fp)        # Restore the value of the frame pointer
    addiu   $sp, $sp, 52        # Restore the value of the stack pointer
    j       $ra
    nop     

    .end main
```

Now putting aside the fact that the code is not very efficient and I am using the frame pointer in a slightly different way than the MIPS convention, I restore the initial values of `$sp` and `$fp`, which is all my code needs to run together with other functions.

The problem is I am getting segfault when I try to access memory address `24($fp)` (around the bottom of the assembly). If I try to access the memory location via `$sp` it all works correctly. Moreover, if I allocate the total memory at the beginning of the function (i.e. `addiu   $sp, $sp, -52` and don't perform a second allocation) it works correctly as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you think `24($fp)` makes sense? You allocate 24 bytes from the stack, then point `$fp` 16 bytes into it (which is not the bottom, contrary to your comment). So the valid offsets from `$fp` are in the range `[-16, +8)`.

Comment: But I only access 24($fp) after I allocate another 28 bytes... I agree with all other arguments of yours.

Comment: But the allocated stuff will be at more negative addresses from `$fp`. After you allocate those (with `$fp` unchanged), the valid range is of course `[-44, +8)` ... it didn't grow upwards, you subtracted (as you should, since stack grows down).

Comment: Omg thanks so much, that was so obvious... That's why people should not be doing that